# Where is (or why not exist) one `Indexed` type class more generic than `Data.Array`?

Tags: haskell, indexing, typeclass

I'm looking for something like

```
class Indexed a e | a → e where
  size   :: a → Int
  at     :: a → Int → e
```

(probably using [`Ix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#t:Ix))

Then, any *indexable struct* can be accessed by index.

E.g.

```
instance Indexed T.Text Char where
  size = T.length
  at   = T.index

instance Indexed [a] a where
  size = length
  at   = (‼)

count :: (Eq e, Indexed a e) ⇒ a → e → Int
count a e = length $ filter (e≡) $ map (a `at`) [0…size a - 1]
```

then

```
> count ("foo bar foo" :: T.Text) 'o'
4
> count ("foo bar foo" :: String) 'o'
4
```

But (e.g) `Data.Text` and `Data.ByteString` have not instances to some similar class (or I cannot find).

Comment: [`Ixed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.2.1/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#t:Ixed) pretty much is what you're asking for.

Comment: Is not (`lens`) a restriction too big?

Comment: What do you mean, that `lens` is a too big dependency for a small project or that a `Traversal` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: `lens` too big dependency (sorry)

Comment: Well. [Arguably](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-04-24-lens-unidiomatic), but IMO it's not sensible to avoid `lens`.

Comment: @josejuan The less dependency-heavy `microlens-ghc` package has `at` and `ix` combinators.

Comment: I think this doesn't exist because people care about performance (or at least, personal opinion, I wouldn't use it because of performance). Quadratic time to compute occurrences of a character in a `Text` would make me sad. The `Ixed` class from lens is more general - it allows *updating* a sequence-like structure at a certain position.

Comment: @user2407038, `ByteString` `index` is (e.g) `O(1)` but no matter here, the question is you can write generic algorithms (e.g. knuth-morris-pratt for any struct) with only one plain and simple interface. Like `Data.Traversable` I would expect some like `Data.Indexable`, much less restrictive than `Data.Array.IArray` or "heavy" than `lens`.

Comment: `lens` is heavy because it needs to declare lots of instances to avoid orphans. If we had a better way to deal with the orphan instance problem, lens could be much lighter.

Comment: As an important corollary to @dfeuer 's comment, `lens` isn't heavy at runtime. Don't mistake having lots of dependencies for being inefficient. It has all those dependencies for compatibility with all those libraries, not because it's a difficult concept.